# How do you convert an Imagine raster attribute value into the raster value?

Tags: convert, attribute-table, erdas-imagine

I have a raster derived from image segments with row id as the value. I have an attribute in the attribute table which should be the raster value, "Standard deviation layer 5" (see image). How do I convert my raster to that value? Is there a way to do this in Imagine? (I'd like to avoid needing to go to spatial analyst in Arc to run reclassify).

[image: a value raster with id as the value]